# How to substract one day from a date string in Mule using DataWeave

Tags: string, date, mule, dataweave

I want to substract one day from a `date` `string` in Mule using `DataWeave` :

`Exemple:`

```
Input date : 18/03/2017 09:20:55
Output date : 17/03/2017 09:20:55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another alternative, we can follow the example from [Date Time Operations](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators) documentation for *Subtracting a Period of Time*. In that example we can defining the period between '|' characters. For example: `|P1D|`.

Therefore, we can do the following steps to subtract one day from a date **String**:

1. Transform the date **String** to a **Date**: `"18/03/2017 09:20:55" as :localdatetime {format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}`
2. Subtract one day: `[the Date on step #1] - |P1D|`
3. Transform the **Date** back to **String**: `[the subtracted Date on step #2] as :string {format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}`

Comment: Can i put all this thing in one dataweave ?

Comment: Yes, you can. I separated the steps to make it clear.  Please group each step inside a bracket, to avoid error or unexpected result. For example: `((step1) step2) step3`

Answer (score 1):

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var aPeriod=("P" ++ 1 ++ "D") as :period
%var cDatetime= now as :datetime {format: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"} 
---
{
previousDate: (cDatetime - aPeriod) as :datetime {format: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

{ currentdateTime: (now as :localdatetime {format : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"})as :string {format : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}, beforedate: ((currentdateTime) - |P1D|)as :string {format : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"} }